# Subclassing datetime: Is there a better way to maintain resulting object type after arithmetic operations?

Tags: python

I recently ran into a situatiton where I needed to subclass `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta` in order to add a few methods.  I immediately found, though, that any arithmetic operations would return a `datetime.datetime` object when I expected it to return a `mydatetime.mydatetime` instance instead.  Below is the solution that a co-worker helped me out with for this problem.  Does anyone have a more concise or convenient suggestion?  Are there any dangers to what I have done here?  Am I missing anything important?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def _to_mydatetime(native):
    '''Instantiates object of appropriate class based on class
    of the input object.'''
    if hasattr(native, 'timetuple'):
        return mydatetime(*native.timetuple()[:6])
    else:
        return mytimedelta(native.days, native.seconds)

class mydatetime(datetime):
    '''Subclass of datetime'''
    def __add__(self, other):
        result = super(mydatetime, self).__add__(other)
        return _to_mydatetime(result)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        result = super(mydatetime, self).__sub__(other)
        return _to_mydatetime(result)

class mytimedelta(timedelta):
    def __add__(self, other):
        result = super(mytimedelta, self).__add__(other)
        return _to_mydatetime(result)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        result = super(mytimedelta, self).__sub__(other)
        return _to_mydatetime(result)

    def __div__(self, other):
        result = super(mytimedelta, self).__div__(other)
        return _to_mydatetime(result)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        result = super(mytimedelta, self).__rmul__(other)
        return _to_mydatetime(result)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        result = super(mytimedelta, self).__mul__(other)
        return _to_mydatetime(result)
```

Comment: Just want to mention you should use StudlyCaps class names per standard convention.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.  I'll go fix that tomorrow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the right way to do it (i'd just split the converter method into two). Python allows you to reduce code duplication though:

```
from datetime import *

def convproxy(methods,converter):
    def f(cls):
        def _proxyfactory(method):
            def _convproxy(self,*args,**kwargs):
                return converter(getattr(super(cls,self),method)(*args,**kwargs))
            return _convproxy
        for m in methods:
            setattr(cls,m,_proxyfactory(m))
        return cls
    return f

@convproxy(('__add__','__sub__'),lambda d:mydatetime(d.timetuple()[:6]))
class mydatetime(datetime):
    pass

@convproxy(('__add__','__sub__','__div__','__rmul__','__mul__'),\
        lambda t:mytimetuple(t.days,t.seconds))
class mytimedelta(timedelta):
    pass
```

The cryptic code under `convproxy` is just a smart-aleck way to generate the specified methods when creating a class, each of which calls a superclass method and creates a subclass from the result using the specified converter function.

Comment: While this solution is interesting, and less lines of code, IMHO this unnecessarily complicates the implementation for THIS problem.  Another more complex problem might warrant something like this though.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I can definitely see where convproxy could come in handy.  I think that Derek is right in this situation that convproxy is probably a good way to confuse the issue in a simple problem like this.  I feel better about the solution I'm using for this situation now.

Comment: BTW, I shouldn't have split the conversion method into two. I didn't put into consideration that `datetime`'s methods may return `timedelta` and vice-versa.